# Adding a keyboard shortcut to the compile process in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, viewers

I am using TeXnicCenter, and have just updated to Adobe Reader X. All in all I'm doing okay with the change, but I have one minor tweak that I'd want to make: I prefer the "Read Mode" view in Adobe Reader X, but AFAIK there is no way of setting that to be the default view in the standalone reader (it is the default view in a browser, however).

What I would like is some method of automatically switching to Read Mode after the compile process is complete. The approach I was thinking of (though I would welcome any alternatives!) was to use the keyboard shortcut for switching to Read Mode (it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>). I have a macro recording program on my computer, so I can record

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>    *Delay[x milliseconds]*   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

which will compile and display the document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), wait `x` milliseconds, then switch to Read Mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), but the problem is that depending on the packages being loaded, the compilation time for different documents can vary widely, and I'd like the delay between the two key combinations to be no longer than necessary. If the PDF output hasn't been opened by the end of the delay, the TeXnicCenter window is still in focus and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> is applied there.

My question is whether there is a way of incorporating the command "apply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>" into the LaTeX => PDF output profile, and specifically, in a manner such that it will be executed directly after the PDF output has been opened. Perhaps there is something I can add to that "Command" field under "View project's output"?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/texniccenter-dde-commands-for-acrobat.html). Perhaps you can use the `MenuitemExecute` DDE to switch to read mode.

Comment: @wh1t3 Aha, that looks like it would be the right way to go! Unfortunately after some further digging around I came across [Adobe's specifications](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACOverview.pdf) for DDE and it appears (page 43) that Reader doesn't support MenuItemExecute. However I expect that if I had the full copy of Acrobat this could be made to work successfully. I guess this likely means that there's no non-jury-rigged way of doing it.

Comment: How about [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) ? I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/wiki/DDEcommands) but didn't test it. Look for `Set view settings`

Comment: If you use TeXmaker then you can have split-screen code and output which, IMHO, is the best thing ever! Then, use the shortcut key F1 to compile and viol-la, your document has compiled, been output on screen and is showing the line that you last edited. Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

*Also with the recently published version 2.0 beta 1 of TeXnicCenter the simple, but unsatisfactory answer is:*

**No, there is no solution inside of TeXnicCenter.**

Nevertheless some ideas:

- Was always suggested by percusse: Use [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html). It supports DDE commands, cf. [DDE commands for SumatraPDF](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/wiki/DDEcommands). It has a presentation mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and a fullscreen modus with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>. See, if one of them fits your favorite read mode of Adobe Reader. This program reloads the PDF itself, no need for closing.
  In the rare cases, if you are really in need of opening a PDF file in Adobe Reader, you can do this from the “File” menu in SumatraPDF, and it will be redirected to the same active page. *(Also, if you installed other PDF readers, you can open the file in these from this menu.)*
- Use [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). It has a very similar read mode (key <kbd>F11</kbd>). PDF-XChange Viewer does not support DDE commands, but command line arguments instead, one is for closing. For this see in the manual file available as separate download, but included in the installer version.
  If you really need to open a PDF file in Adobe Reader, you can do this from a symbol inside of PDF-XChange Viewer, and again it will be redirected to the same active page. The read mode is remembered by the program also after closing.
- Use a program like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) as your “PDF Viewer”. Of course, then you are yourself responsible for programming the open and close rules for your actual PDF Viewer.