# keyboard shortcut does not work in TEXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I have recently used TXnicCenter . But it is a matter of surprise that keyboard shortcut is not working here . Like I am trying to select all text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or want to build output by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> But no shortcut is working here .

What could be the probable solution ? My keyboard is completely right because it works in Microsoft office .

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Are all of the shortcuts not functioning or just few of them? If latter, Perhaps [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/adding-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-the-compile-process-in-texniccenter) question and its answers can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools->Customize and then you will get the following picture . Then assign the shortcut key according to your feasibility .

[image]